# MVC: Displaying table after button pressed

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi I have a question is that possible to have function to display my table after the button was pressed, because now it's always on? I've tried with some IF functions but they weren't working. 
My code:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        <br />
        <span style="font-weight: bold">Tytuł filmu:</span> @Html.TextBox("VideoName")
        <input type="submit" value="Szukaj" class="btn-primary" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ImageUrl)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.VideoName)
                </th>
            </tr>

            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ImageUrl)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.VideoName)
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </table>
    }
```

Comment: So you want a form submission to load the results into the same view? After the submission the original form is also on the same page?

Comment: Yes, it all happens in one view

Answer (score 0):

If you put your markup inside a conditional block as follows:

```
@if (true)
{
   @* PUT MARKUP HERE *@
}
```

Then the markup will only appear when the `if` condition is true.

Alternatively, you can use client-side code to simply hide the markup. I don't know which is best, because you haven't provided any details about what you are doing.

Instead of saying **THE** button, perhaps you should've talked about what kind of button you have and what is it supposed to do. If it works server side, use my first suggestion. If it needs to work client side, use my second suggestion.

Comment: The button is for searching is on my project site, whenever I type a phrase into textbox and click search it should show me my films

Comment: Ok, well that doesn't clarify anything I was asking. I'm going to guess you want it to be displayed client-side, in which case just give your form a style like "display: none". And then you'd need client script to make it visible.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a button that toggles the visibility of the table, call the below function on the button onclick event to show or hide the table.

```
function toggleTable() {
    var lTable = document.getElementById("YourTableId");
    lTable.style.display = (lTable.style.display == "table") ? "none" : "table";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in number of ways,

- Javascript:

  document.getElementById('mytable').style.display = 'block';
  Give your table an ID and set its display to `none;` initially, then using javascript on the button click switch the table display to `block;`

```js
 function buttonClick(){
    document.getElementById('myTable').style.display = 'block';
 }
```

```html
 <table id='myTable' style='display:none;'>...</table>
 <input type="submit" value="Szukaj" class="btn-primary" onclick='buttonClick()' />
```

Notes:
- It can be much easier if you are using jquery
- You can use event listener for the button click

- Server side code:
  On your action method set a TempData or ViewBag variable and then in the html check if this value exist, if true show the table

I am sure there are many other ways to do that but most of them will be around both ideas I listed.

Answer (score 0):

You have several good answers but it depends on exactly what you are trying to accomplish.  I've used a variety of what has been provided.  You mention showing table on button click.  Do you also need to hide table if said button is clicked again?  If so, client side jQuery and .toggle() could help.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("#myTable").toggle();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Toggle</button>    
<table id="myTable" style="border: 1px solid black; display: none">
  <tr>
    <th>Header 1</th>
    <th>Header 2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Data 1</td>
    <td>Data 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Yeah but it has to show me my table search result additionally